# Issue in trigger after enabling state and country picklist feature

Tags: trigger

I have enabled State and Country picklist feature in my org. Now MalingCountry in Contact object appears as picklist.

I have a trigger on Contact object as shown below-

```
public void OnBeforeInsert(List<Contact> newContacts) {
for(Contact con : newContacts){

         if(con.AccountId == null){
              if (Con.RecordTypeid == Utility.getRecordTypeId('Contact','Household Contact')){            
                    Account acc = new Account();

                    acc.Name = con.LastName + ', ' + con.FirstName + ' '+ con.Salutation +' Household';     //added by Rohit
                    acc.BillingStreet = con.MailingStreet;
                    acc.BillingCity = con.MailingCity;
                    acc.BillingState = con.MailingState;
                    acc.BillingCountry = con.MailingCountry;
                    acc.BillingPostalCode = con.MailingPostalCode;
     }
}
}
}
```

In code, MalingCountry and MailingState is coming as null even though I am selecting value from picklist. But on detail page of contact record I see the selected MalingCountry and MailingState.

Any help/suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using `MalingCountryCode` and `MailingStateCode` fields instead.

Comment: But as I am able to select MailingCountry when trying to create contact record though Back-office, why can't I use it in code?

Comment: In backend salesforce uses Code field, so please try that.

Comment: Nice. posting it as a answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After enabling the feature- [Enable and Disable State and Country Picklists](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_state_country_picklist_enable.htm&type=0), best practice is to use StateCode and CountryCode fields instead, It specifies ISO code.

The label is displayed just for UI, to manage them use Code fields.

In your example, you can try code as follows:

```
acc.BillingStateCode = con.MailingStateCode;
acc.BillingCountryCode = con.MailingCountryCode;
```